# Error in javascript

Tags: javascript, list

I am trying to get a collapsible link list to work using JavaScript.

However, there is a continual error in the Java document and I don't know why:

```
var css Node = document.createElement('link');
cssNode.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
cssNode.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
cssNode.setAttribute('href', 'javascript-overrides.css');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cssnode);

function toggle(toggler) {

    if (document.getElementById) {
        targetElement = toggler.nextsibling;
        if (targetElement.classname == undefined) {
            targetElement = toggler.nextsiblig.nextsibling;
        }
        if {
            targetElement.style.display == "block") {
            targetElement.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            targetElement.style.display = "block"
        }
    }
}

function swap(targetid) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        target = document.getElementById(targetid);
        if (target.style.display == "block") {
            target.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            target.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

The error in on line 15 where is states `"if ( document.getElementById){"` but it seems fine to me.

Any advice?

Comment: @Welling Error ? Where is the line !   :-)

Comment: Why is there a space in `var css Node = document.createElement('link');` between `css` and `Node`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/) returns 3 errors (and assuming your first line is `var cssNode`)

- Compare to undefined with ===  ( `if (targetElement.classname === undefined)` )
- `if { targetElement.style.display == "block")}` must be if **(**
- Missing semicolon (`targetElement.style.display = "block"`)

Broken [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SP8vM/1/) (Push the jsLint button to see the errors)

Fixed [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SP8vM/)